# What is the exact meaning of [statistics]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33894/how-i-figure-what-dice-i-need-to-attain-a-certain-curve) was tagged with the tag [statistics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics). However, I thought the term "statistics" were tied to attribute, ability scores, or any other numbers and traits which systematically specify the character's strength and weaknesses in RPG context, and there **is** [a question which fits this meaning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25333/questions-about-improved-familiar-advancement).

Since there is no tag wiki and there are both kinds of questions, here I present a question. What does [statistics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics) tag mean?

- Is it tied to *mathematical* statistics, as the first question is tied to?
- Is it tied to statistics *on a sheet*, as the second question is tied to?
- Is it supposed to mean something else, or a combination of multiple candidates?

Comment: Statistics as a tag is iffy and ambiguous. A tag wiki entry would be best. It should be about the math; stuff on sheets is called many ambiguous things, and the only time we'd generalize it would be times where a general "records" tag would perhaps be more appropriate.

Comment: Worth noting: 8 of the existing questions tagged [tag:statistics] refer to math/probability. Only one refers to a character's attributes.

Comment: @AceCalhoon That's an interesting statistic. *ducks*

Answer (score 12):

I propose we make a tag synonym to [probability](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability) and take it off entirely from questions that don't fit (they can probably just have the relevant system tags, or [character-creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-creation) or whatever else).

Comment: Good point, since I couldn't think how different [probability] and [statistics] are, but I doubt whether I have such a privilege.

Comment: For our intents and purposes they're identical. Technically, statistics mostly ignores probability and is more about data presentation, but from a game perspective probability is the only part of statistics we care about, and it's more true to the common-language usage.

Comment: `[mtg:character-creation]` Umm, clearly I use the MTG tag way, *waaaay* too much (on B&CG).

Comment: @KyleWilley Hmm. The questions I can think of as falling under the actual concept of "statistics" are few and far between. I'm imagining something like a "What percentage of D&D organized play characters are casters?" >.>

Comment: Yeah, we don't really do real "statistics", and really only care about it in the context of probability, since people usually don't come to rpg.se to ask about organized play stuff.

Comment: How about rather merging [probability] into [statistics], as probability is one aspect of RPG-wise statistics we look for?

Comment: @ArleCamille Well, our probability questions aren't *really* about statistics, for the most part. And going probability->statistics doesn't solve the problem of having the "statistics" tag on questions about, like, Constitution modifiers.

Answer (score 5):

The math kind. You could contribute to clarification by submitting a tag wiki.

We have [probability] too which is somewhat redundant with that...

For "character stats" - if that's even a valid tag, and I'm not really sure it is - we could put in something else, perhaps [ability-scores], but I am not sure it's really a valid tag.

Comment: Character stats are usually single game related; if it's related to something like character sheet design, a record-keeping tag would be better, and if it relates to a single game it should be kept relevant to that game, as Fate, d20, and Shadowrun (to name three games off the top of my head) each keep wildly different attributes that should be measured in different ways.